# Handle ApplicationCommands in CustomControl

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, command

How do I wire ApplicationCommand.Undo to handlers in a custom control?

Some code snippets would be most welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Undo, UndoExecuted, CanUndo));